# polygon angle names

Tags: polygons, angle

Regular polygons can be divided up into triangles of equal sizes.  For example, a pentagon would have 5 triangles.  Each would have one angle with a value of 72 degrees and two angles of 54 degrees.

What are the names, if anything, of those 72 and 54 degree angles?

I know for a polygon with five sides the name of the 108 degree angle is the "interior angle", and am looking for the name of the other two.

[image of a regular pentagon](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/01/Regular_polygon_5_annotated.svg/2000px-Regular_polygon_5_annotated.svg.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would refer to the 54 degree angle as simply half of the interior angle...  No need for additional terms if you don't need them!!  The 72 degree angle is one of the exterior angles...  Notice that the sum of the exterior angles for any regular polygon is 360